# Mutably borrowing in match statement and result

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to determine if a container has an object and return the found object if it does, or add it if it doesn't.

I've found [Rust borrow mutable self inside match expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908383/rust-borrow-mutable-self-inside-match-expression)
which has an answer which says what I am trying to do can't (couldn't?) be done.

In my situation, I've got some objects that have vectors of children. I don't want to expose the internals of my object, because I may want to change the representation underneath.

[How can you resolve the need to mutably borrow in different match arms in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023441/how-can-you-resolve-the-need-to-mutably-borrow-in-different-match-arms-in-rust/) seems to suggest I may be able to do what I want if I get the lifetimes correct, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Here's a representation of the issue I'm having:

```
fn find_val<'a>(container: &'a mut Vec<i32>, to_find: i32) -> Option<&'a mut i32> {
    for item in container.iter_mut() {
        if *item == to_find {
            return Some(item);
        }
    }

    None
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Vec::<i32>::new();
    container.push(1);
    container.push(2);
    container.push(3);

    let to_find = 4;

    match find_val(&mut container, to_find) {
        Some(x) => {
            println!("Found {}", x);
        }
        _ => {
            container.push(to_find);
            println!("Added {}", to_find);
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d97d531b2c7d0c6a3fb793efed4c186b&version=stable)

The error I get is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `container` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:24:13
   |
19 |     match find_val(&mut container, to_find) {
   |                         --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
24 |             container.push(to_find);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
27 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the change in a function, and use early return instead of an `else` branch:

```
fn find_val_or_insert(container: &mut Vec<i32>, to_find: i32) {
    if let Some(x) = find_val(&container, to_find) {
        println!("Found {}", x);
        return; // <- return here instead of an else branch
    }
    container.push(to_find);
    println!("Added {}", to_find);
}
```

See also [Mutable borrow more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067348/mutable-borrow-more-than-once/49068081) and [How to update-or-insert on a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395171/how-to-update-or-insert-on-a-vec)